# Magento 2 New Product Collection - Specific Attribute

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.3

I want to create a new widget for products that are "coming soon"

Coming soon is a toggle attribute.
I have found example codes online, but none of the answers contain file paths.

How would I create this collection? (i.e. code correction and specifically in which file)

Code I think will work :

```
 <?php namespace Vendor\Yourmodule\Block; class ProductCollection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {protected $_productCollectionFactory; public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,        
    array $data = []
)
{    
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
     $collection->addAttributeToFilter('coming_soon', array('eq' => 'coming_soon'));

    return $collection;
}
```

}

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a module and call this block in phtml file. Since you want to create a widget ideally you need to create cms block first and call this block template file in it.

like

```
    {{block class="Vendor\Yourmodule\Block" 
        template="Vendor_Yourmodule::coming_soon.phtml"
        name="formblock" 
        template="advanced/form.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Thank you, but which file or folder would I add it to? I'm still confused about where exactly to put the code in my original question

Answer (score 0):

What you have described is a featured product extension

https://github.com/DominicWatts/Featured

All you need to do is rename code and label of attribute to coming soon

Or keep attribute label and code the same. Just change the title on the widget and / or landing page.

## Update

The extension contains logic to create attribute code, landing page and allow configuration of widget in backend

Here is the widget block collection

https://github.com/DominicWatts/Featured/blob/3836952888ac630e3c53fcb54df46497265d72e9/Block/Widget/Featured.php#L78-L91

```
    protected function _getFeaturedProductsCollection()
    {
        /** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->setVisibility($this->_catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
        $collection->getSelect()->orderRand();
        $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('featured', ['eq' => 1])
            ->setPageSize($this->getPageSize())
            ->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());
        return $collection;
    }
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. I already have an extension, I want to add a collection to it.